# Export DataFrame of dictionaries to JSON file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
have_df = pd.DataFrame({'User':['101','101','101'],'json_text':["""{"president":{"name": "Zaphod Beeblebrox","species": "Betelgeusian"}}""","""{"president":{"name": "Zaphod Beeblebrox","species": "Betelgeusian"}}""",'blank']})
```

and I want this export pipe delimited file and tried this:

```
have_df.to_csv('have_df.csv',sep="|")
```

when I opened and see the pipe file the there's an extra double quotes around the json text values like this:

```
"{""president"":{""name"": ""Zaphod Beeblebrox"",""species"": ""Betelgeusian""}}"
```

how to remove this extra double quotes programmatic way? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eval your JSON data first, and then save to csv:

```
import json

(have_df.json_text
        .replace('blank', "None")
        .apply(ast.literal_eval)
        .to_csv('file.csv', sep='|')
)
```

`file.csv`

```
0|{'president': {'name': 'Zaphod Beeblebrox', 'species': 'Betelgeusian'}}
1|{'president': {'name': 'Zaphod Beeblebrox', 'species': 'Betelgeusian'}}
2|
```

Comment: @KumarAK `import ast` in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have json string convert it using `json.loads` and should fix your issue

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
import json

def converttojson(val):
    try:
        return json.loads(val)
    except:
        return val

have_df = pd.DataFrame({'User':['101','101','101'],'json_text':["""{"president":{"name": "Zaphod Beeblebrox","species": "Betelgeusian"}}""","""{"president":{"name": "Zaphod Beeblebrox","species": "Betelgeusian"}}""",'blank']})
have_df["json_text"] = have_df["json_text"].apply(converttojson)
have_df.to_csv(filename,sep="|")
```

- Note -- You can use `have_df["json_text"].apply(json.loads)` directly. But i have used `converttojson` because you have `blank` in your sample data